# parse saveInBackground

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have a class called `relationship` that has a `read` column which is of type `Boolean`

```
relationship[@"read"] = @YES;
[userToMessageRelationship saveInBackground];
```

This works only ***some*** of  the time, however it's extremely important that this works 100% of the time given the nature of my app. I don't know exactly how saveInBackground works, but is there a different method in the Parse API for saving values that's more reliable.

The only thing I can think of that might be causing this capricious behavior is that I save the relationship via `NSArchiver` (`NSCoding` provided by this [this](https://github.com/updatezen/Parse-NSCoding) api). Then I load it back from file with `NSUnarchiver`. I don't see why this would affect saveInBackground though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For boolean values, use

```
relationship[@"read"] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
```

saveInBackground always works, but you can use saveInBackgroundWithBlock to add some code that triggers if the save is unsuccessful:

```
[object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        // Test for succeeded or error here
    }];
```

Comment: why [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] as opposed to YES. What's the difference? Thanks

Comment: Although YES will probably work, numberWithBool is the convention. Here is also an explanation why it is preferable: https://www.parse.com/questions/a-boolean-data-type

Comment: Some more info: You can use YES as well, but then it would be using the literal way: relationship[@"read"] = @YES;